# Can I set jQuery's accordion depending on browser's window width?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-accordion

This script is working perfectly if I click Menu(h3), it does shrinks whole menu to minimum height.
Then I click again, it expands back to the original size.

Today, there are two kinds of viewer such as PC and Smart Phone.

I'd like to make this menu appear as the size of minimum as default when a viewer is seeing this page with smartphone, whose browser width is less than 400px.
Minimum size means the size of the height when accordion is closed.
Is it possible?

**javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    $(".accordion dt").click(function(){
        $(this).next("dd").slideToggle();
        $(this).next("dd").siblings("dd").slideUp();
        $(this).toggleClass("open");   
    $(this).siblings("dt").removeClass("open");
});
```

**html**

```
<div class="accordion">
    <dt><h3>Menu</h3></dt>
    <dd>
    Menu Contents
    </dd>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

```
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') > 0 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') == -1) || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') > 0 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') > 0) {
        1. I want to show Menu as minimum size(Shrinked size)
    }else {
        2. I want to show Menu as maximum size(Expanded size)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to decide the exact form of the code without more information about exactly what you are trying to do. If you want to check the type of browser viewing the page, I would recommend matching **navigator.userAgent** string with common mobile browsers like this:

```
var sUserAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var bMobileBrowser = (sUserAgent.indexOf('iphone') !== -1) || (sUserAgent.indexOf('android') !== -1) || (sUserAgent.indexOf('mobile') !== -1);

if(bMobileBrowser) {
  // Do something special if it's a mobile browser
}
```

That being said, if you're set on varying your content according to the size of the browser window, jQuery furnishes you with the handy cross-browser methods **$(window).width()** and **$(window).height()** which respectively return the width and the height of the viewport in pixels (shocker!). In your case the code might look something like this:

```
// This is a much shorter (and my preferred) way of writing jQuery(document).ready
$(function() {

  // Why bother rewrapping '.accordion dt' in a new selector every time its referenced?
  var $accordionHeader = $(".accordion dt");

  $accordionHeader.click(function() {
    $accordionHeader.next("dd").slideToggle();
    $accordionHeader.next("dd").siblings("dd").slideUp();
    $accordionHeader.toggleClass("open");   
    $accordionHeader.siblings("dt").removeClass("open");
  });

  // Toggle the accordion if the browser window's width is less than 400px
  if($(window).width() < 400) $accordionHeader.click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion looks so useful:) By the way, You defined iphone, android, and mobile. This is for sure? or you just mentioned as examples? Do I need to be really sensitive about there?

Comment: I have 4 lines within `$(".accordion dt").click(function(){`. Please see my update

Comment: Could you please check my update in question? and I want to know what to code in 1. and 2.  It can be quoted from my original script.

Comment: @MKK I defined iphone, android, and mobile as suggestions. My goal was to match iPhones, Android phones, and Opera mobile. You can find more user agent strings here: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/.

Comment: @MKK I hate to be bipolar on this issue, but I've changed my mind; I think it would make more sense to decided the content based on the viewport width since tablets may register as mobile browsers but have wide screens. That being said, my second example should work for you. Assuming the starts out expanded, the code triggers a click (which I imagine toggles the menu to the smaller state) if the viewport is less than 400px.

Comment: @MKK Again assuming the menu starts out in the expanded state, you should be able to programmatically click it to toggle it. So I don't think you need (2) and (1) would look like `$(".accordion dt").click();`. As a side note, make sure you wrap that check in a `$(function(){});` so that the click isn't fired before it is bound.